# Sitecore Solr query in C# combination of AND and OR condition

Tags: solr, sitecore-query

I want to search all the pages, based on "Template A" or "Template B" or "Template C" and page should be inside this location "/sitecore/content/Home/Services/"

I am trying to filter the pages with below code.

```
List<SearchResultItem> results = null;
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(sitecoreSxaWebIndex).CreateSearchContext())
{
   results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
       .Where(item => (item.Path.StartsWith("/sitecore/content/Home/Services/")) && 
           (item.TemplateName == "Template A") || 
           (item.TemplateName == "Template B") || 
           (item.TemplateName == "Template C"))
       .ToList();
}
```

**Issue:**  It is filtering pages from outside the path which I have provided as well. Could you please help me with form the query to fulfill my combination of AND and OR condition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the looks of it if you are using SXA you should be using the services they provide to perform a search. SXA comes with a search service that will automatically narrow down results to the appropriate home item. There are other things in there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you got the couple of brackets wrong in your condition

```
List<SearchResultItem> results = null;
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(sitecoreSxaWebIndex).CreateSearchContext())
{
     results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
         .Where(item => item.Path.StartsWith("/sitecore/content/Home/Services/") && 
             (item.TemplateName == "Template A" || 
             item.TemplateName == "Template B" || 
             item.TemplateName == "Template C"))
         .ToList();
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. It works

Comment: Please, do not use names when working with Sitecore items. Use IDs instead. If you will update the template name all your code will break.